# How separate Tables creation of db_session in flask working with Pony ORM

Tags: python, flask, ponyorm

I'm trying to separate this two aspects in a model folder. 
I have got: pony.orm.core.ERDiagramError: Cannot define entity 'Guest': database mapping has already been generated

this is the code

******* db_session.py *******

```
from pony import orm
from model.dbase import (Guest, Offer, Payment_method, Extra_services,
                     Voucher, Reservation, db)

db = orm.Database()

class GuestManager(object):
    @orm.db_session
    def show_guest(n):
        guest = Guest[n]
        return guest
```

***** dbase.py *****

```
from datetime import date
from pony import orm

db = orm.Database()

db.bind(provider='sqlite', filename='database.sqlite')
orm.sql_debug(True)
db.generate_mapping(create_tables=True)

class Guest(db.Entity):
    nome = orm.Required(str)
    surname = orm.Required(str)
    email = orm.Required(str, unique=True)
```

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should solve the issue.

```
from pony import orm
from model.dbase import (Guest, Offer, Payment_method, Extra_services,
                         Voucher, Reservation, db)


class GuestManager(object):
    @orm.db_session
    def show_guest(n):
        guest = Guest[n]
        return guest
```

***** dbase.py *****

```
from datetime import date
from pony import orm

db = orm.Database()

db.bind(provider='sqlite', filename='database.sqlite')
orm.sql_debug(True)

class Guest(db.Entity):
    nome = orm.Required(str)
    surname = orm.Required(str)
    email = orm.Required(str, unique=True)

db.generate_mapping(create_tables=True)
```

You dont want to create your tables everytime, unless you are starting with a fresh db.

[Here](https://github.com/ponyorm/pony/issues/44) is a good issue about this on the repo

Answer (score 1):

you could add database initialization at start up project, commonly **__init__.py** file.

> **__init__.py**

```
from datetime import date
from pony import orm

db = orm.Database()

def startup_database():
    db.bind(provider='sqlite', filename='database.sqlite', create_db=True)
    db.generate_mapping(create_tables=True)
    orm.sql_debug(True)

def main():
    startup_database() # If you have another methods, THIS LINE SHOULD BE THE LAST ONE

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Then, define your models in other file:

> **models.py**

```
from pony import orm

# 'db' variable it's included by own because it's on __init__.py file
# You could migrate to another file form __init__.py and import that module here
class Guest(db.Entity):
    nome = orm.Required(str)
    surname = orm.Required(str)
    email = orm.Required(str, unique=True)
```

And create a manager database into another file

> **manager.py**

```
from pony import orm
from models import Guest # Add another models that you have

class GuestManager(object):
    @orm.db_session
    def show_guest(n):
        guest = Guest[n]
        return guest
```

You may create any architecture you prefer. I hope it help you!

Comment: Thank you Juan!! Muy clara y útil la explicación. ;)